# Does the clipping function in QGIS clip the data relevent to each polygon?

Tags: polygon, vector, clip

I am looking to clip geographical areas with population data already inputted. My question is: Assume I clip a polygon containing 100 people in half, will the newly clipped polygon report there to be 100 people or 50 people in it? If not, is there a plug-in I could use to do this?

Comment: There's basic maths and the field calculator, which will suffice for such calculations.

Comment: It is almost always wrong to assume uniform population disaggregation. The population experts are quite insistent that you should only aggregate their data. Fortunately, most Clip tools will not tamper with data like this.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It is not actually essential to the nature of the project to get the population figures perfect, once it is approximated, it will do

Comment: you would have to compute `old field value * new area / old area` yourself. Beside the spatial distribution aspect, this ratio is valid only for counts or sums. Here are some example to think about `field1 = average_income` (if avg is 100 000, splitting the polygon in 2 does not imply the new average is 50 000 in each polygon). `field2 = highest_altitude` (the highest value should remain "somewhere" and a totally  new value should be found "elsewhere"), `field3 = population_density` ... assuming a uniform spatial distribution, the density of the split polygon should remain the same